# How to convert Simd::View to cv::Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv, simd-library

I want to use [OpenCV 3.2](https://github.com/opencv/opencv) and [Simd](https://github.com/ermig1979/Simd) in one c++ project.
Is there easy way to convert cv::Mat (image type in OpenCV) to Simd::View (image type used in Simd Library)?
Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple. You just have to define macro SIMD_OPENCV_ENABLE before including of Simd headers:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#define SIMD_OPENCV_ENABLE
#include "Simd/SimdLib.hpp"

typedef Simd::View<Simd::Allocator> View;

void test()
{
    cv::Mat cvImage;
    View simdImage;

    cvImage = simdImage;
    simdImage = cvImage;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It is simpler than I thought.